# django csrf gives forbidden 403 error for POST

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm trying to learning Django and as part of a tutorial, i was trying to pass some data through forms. It was good with GET, but POST gives me a forbidden 403. I googled and applied many of those tricks but nothing helped.

Here is my code:

**view**

```
@csrf_protect
def counter(request):
    template = loader.get_template("counter.html")
    ss = request.POST["cnt"]
    context = {
        "words" : len(ss.split(" "))
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**form**

```
<form method="post" action="counter">
{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="cnt" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The 403 error at first was:

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Help Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing.

But after removing cookies (I read that it might be an issue with the cookie), it changed to:

> Forbidden (403)
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
> You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
> If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.

---

This issue only solves when i comment out 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in the settings, and remove {% csrf_token %} out of html form.

Comment: Have you checked that the token is part of the HTML output? Which CSRF congigurations have you enabled in the settings?

Comment: @Marco, little more details please, as i said im learning. it's not a serious project. anyway, in the settings, the middleware contains: 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Comment: by the way, if by HTML output you mean source of the page, i have to say no, instead of {% csrf_token %} an empty line appears.

Comment: Share your urls.

Comment: from django.urls import path
from . import views

the url.py:    urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("counter", views.counter, name="counter"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
]

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided you wanted to get the length after splitting the value of what is entered in the textarea. In order to do this, try using request.POST.get('cnt'). This will get the value for you.

Comment: unfortunately no. the same 403 showed up

Answer (score 0):

The middleware already protects this, by using `@csrf_protect`, you check this a second time, hence the error:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# no @csrf_protect, but still enable CsrfViewMiddleware
def counter(request):
    context = {'words': len(request.POST['cnt'].split())}
    return render(request, 'counter.html', context)
```

In the template, I would also advise to let Django determine the (absolute) URL, so:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'counter %}">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  <textarea name="cnt" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: didn't work. removing decorator (and re-enabling     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', in the settings, cause that 403 error (CSRF token missing)

Thanks for the {% url 'counter' %} trick. it worked perfectly